# React native picker looks good in andriod but awful in ios

Tags: android, ios, react-native, picker

I use a react native picker for three different things the user has to fill in to report his/her time to the company. It all looks good on Android with a small field that you click then the options popup but in ios it becomes this huge field where you cycle throu the options. I thought this was a common problem bu cant seem to find how people do to make it look similar to the android way.

anyone have any idea or perhaps doen this before?

Comment: can you post a screen shot or sample code for this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe, you can assign a different style depending of the platform ( Android - IOS):

```
    import { Platform, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

    function SubmitBtn ({ onPress }) {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity style={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? styles.iosSubmitBtn : styles.androidSubmitBtn} onPress={onPress}>
              <Text style={styles.submitBtnText}>Submit</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    iosSubmitBtn: {
        backgroundColor: lightPurp,
        marginTop: 50,
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 7,
        height: 45,
        marginLeft: 20,
        marginRight: 20,
    },

    androidSubmitBtn: {
        backgroundColor: lightPurp,
        marginTop: 50,
        padding: 10,
        paddingLeft: 30,
        paddingRight: 30,
        height: 45,
        borderRadius: 2,
        marginLeft: 20,
        marginRight: 20,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },

    submitBtnText: {
        color: white,
        fontSize: 22,
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
});
```

Comment: why is this a correct answer when question is about picker?

Comment: Is a general example about how manage the ui in both: andriod - ios